# Create a new Tuple with one element modified

Tags: python, iterator, ironpython, generator

(I am working interactively with a WordprocessingDocument object in IronPython using the OpenXML SDK, but this is really a general Python question that should be applicable across all implementations)

I am trying to scrape out some tables from a number of Word documents. For each table, 
I have an iterator that is giving me table row objects. I then use the following generator statement to get a tuple of cells from each row:

```
for row in rows:
    t = tuple([c.InnerText for c in row.Descendants[TableCell]()])
```

Each tuple contains 4 elements. Now, in column `t[1]` for each tuple, I need to apply a regex to the data. I know that tuples are immutable, so I'm happy to either create a new tuple, or build the tuple in a different way. Given that `row.Descendants[TableCell]()` returns an iterator, what's the most Pythonic (or at least simplest) way to construct a tuple from an iterator where I want to modify the `n`th element returned?

My brute-force method right now is to create a tuple from the left slice (`t[:n-1]`), the modified data in `t[n]` and the right slice (`t[n+1:]`) but I feel like the `itertools` module should have something to help me out here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def item(i, v):
  if i != 1: return v
  return strangestuff(v)

for row in rows:
  t = tuple(item(i, c.InnerText)
            for i, c in enumerate(row.Descendants[TableCell]())
           )
```

Comment: This is why I should always keep a copy of "Python in a Nutshell" on my desk. I had no idea about the enumerate built-in, having never needed it before. While waiting for responses, I concocted a similar construct using itertools.izip and itertools.count. Thanks Alex!

Comment: @tech&c, you're welcome!  Yes, you could synthesize `enumerate` if it wasn't built-in, but it's a frequently used tool so the compactness and speed are often especially nice to have;-).

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
temp_list = [c.InnerText for c in row.Descendants[TableCell]()]
temp_list[2] = "Something different"
t = tuple(temp_list)
```

It would work like this:

```
>>> temp_list = [i for i in range(4)]
>>> temp_list[2] = "Something different"
>>> t = tuple(temp_list)
>>> t
(0, 1, 'Something different', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If every tuple contains 4 elements, then, frankly, I think you'd be better off assigning them to individual variables, manipulating those, and then building your tuple:

```
for row in rows:
    t1, t2, t3, t4 = tuple([c.InnerText for c in row.Descendants[TableCell]()])
    t1 = ...
    t = (t1, t2, t3, t4)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of columns I'll be working with varies from table to table, so I can't assign each to a concrete variable.

Answer (score 0):

What i've generally done, but am not a fan of:

l = list(oldtuple)
l[2] = foo
t = tuple(l)

I kind of want something like update() for dicts

newtuple = update(oldtuple, (None, None, val, None))

Or perhaps the right structure is a zip

newtuple = update(oldtuple, ((2, val), (3, val)))